# Making a List<string, string, string> in C# with three flexible elements in one datatype

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

Once I have defined a `List<string, string, string>` and now I wanted to do it again but I forgot the syntax and lost the example code where I did that, but I surely know that it was possible. I added a new element to the list this way after I have defined it: `ListXY.Add("string1", "string2", string3");`. My search on the internet and here brought not the results I needed. I definitely insist on a solution with "List", that's why I ask my question now here. I found the workarounds below which do not satisfy me, since I need the simplicity of the usual "List" - nothing else.

I do not primarily search a solution with tuples or own classes or static arrays, since
I have as a beginner difficulty handling complex structures or classes.

Edit: I found meanwhile `Dictionary<string, string>` but I would need three items in there.
I can't remember what I have used, I only know that it was already ready (from MS) contained
in the framework NET 2, had three string elements and I could extend the elements with the .Add method on it. A string array has already a static size I cannot shrink or enlarge it with beginner code. And when I define the variable the final count of elements cannot be foreseen, that's the problem.

If you know the syntax which I have forgotten and cannot find again you may reply me with the right answer.
I am currently search the syntax.

Comment: I think Dave has already pointed out that the `List<T>` type has only 1 generic parameter, and that's the `T`... so at most you have have a `List<string>`, but a `List<string, string, string>` is not happening...

Comment: The data structure you mention, namely `List<T1, T2, T3>` does not exists by default in the C# framework. There is something similar in F#, a [function called `List.zip3`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee370211%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) that returns a `List<T1, T2, T3>`, but I'm unsure if this is what you want...

Comment: What does "You definitely don't know it" mean? If you are suggesting that I'm wrong then I'd point you towards this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Generic.aspx which clearly shows that only `List<T>` is available. You *could* create your own `List<T1, T2, T3>` but I'm not sure what the implementation would look like!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I do not need a solution with saying me to make my own class. I definitely will not re-invent an already existing data-type!" `List<string,string,string>` is not an already existing data type.  You probably did something like this in the past;

```
// Another simple way would be to create a class which has a constructor to hold the three strings
    public class PairedValues
    {
        // These are just simple ways of creating a getter and setter in c#
        public string value1 { get; set; }
        public string value2 { get; set; }
        public string value3 { get; set; }

        // A constructor which sets all your getters and setters
        public PairedValues(string Value1, string Value2, string Value3)
        {
            value1 = Value1;
            value2 = Value2;
            value3 = Value3;
        }
    }
```

Making use of the class;

```
        // Simply initialize a list of your new class
        List<PairedValues> pairedValues = new List<PairedValues>();
        // add you object to the list anonymously 
        pairedValues.Add(new PairedValues("string1","string2","string3"));
        pairedValues.Add(new PairedValues("string1", "string2", "string3"));

        // Accessing the values
        foreach (PairedValues pair in pairedValues)
        {
            string value1 = pair.value1;
            string value2 = pair.value2;
            string value3 = pair.value3;
        }
```

An example using this in windows forms;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Another simple way would be to create a class which has a constructor to hold the three strings
        public class PairedValues
        {
            public string value1 { get; set; }
            public string value2 { get; set; }
            public string value3 { get; set; }

            public PairedValues(string Value1, string Value2, string Value3)
            {
                value1 = Value1;
                value2 = Value2;
                value3 = Value3;
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Simply initialize a list of your new class
            List<PairedValues> pairedValues = new List<PairedValues>();
            pairedValues.Add(new PairedValues("string1", "string2", "string3"));
            pairedValues.Add(new PairedValues("string1", "string2", "string3"));

            // Accessing the values
            foreach (PairedValues pair in pairedValues)
            {
                string value1 = pair.value1;
                string value2 = pair.value2;
                string value3 = pair.value3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @feedwall I have included an example of how to use in win forms.  Feel free to shoot any questions my way and I'll be sure to edit and update my answer as best as possible

Answer (score 13):

If you really don't want to create a class, you can use tuples, they are not that complex.

```
List<Tuple<string,string,string>> items 
= new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>(){ Tuple.Create("a","b","c")};

items.Add(Tuple.Create("1","2","3"));
items.Add(Tuple.Create("4","5","6"));
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're asking for the syntax to initialize a list with multiple elements at once, then:

```
var l = new List<string>{ "string1", "string2", "string3" .... };
```

If you are looking for a way to hold three strings in a single list-item, without using Tuples or custom classes, there's no way to do that, I'm afraid.

EDIT: Unless you're generating strings - in which case you could generate them in an annonymous type, such as:

```
Enumerable
    .Range(1, 100)
    .Select(i => new 
    { 
        string1 = "string1" + i, 
        string2 = "string2" + i, 
        string3 = "string3" + i 
    });
```

But that's really weird.

Also, you could use a list of Lists, such as:

```
var l = new List<List<string>>
{ 
    new List<string> { "string 1", "string 2", "string 3" }, 
    new List<string> { "string 1", "string 2", "string 3" }
};
```

Comment: Maybe a `List<List<List<string>>>`?!

Comment: Well, that is because BCL haven't any collection like this

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of an extension method that you once created.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void Add(this List<String> list, String param1, String param2, String param3)
    {
        list.Add(param1);
        list.Add(param2);
        list.Add(param3);
    }
}
```

Then as long as you have a using for System.Linq, you can invoke this on any List instance:

```
    List<String> stringList = new List<String>();
    stringList.Add("something", "awesome", "here");
```

For more information on extension methods and how they work, go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: Wont this add the string values as three separate elements? I believe the OP wants all three values to act as one element

Comment: It will but I honestly have no idea how else to call List.Add(string, string, string) without creating a new class. The OP seems like he already knows what it is he's looking for, he just forgot what it was, so I'm throwing options out there.